# browser loading by itself, and redirecting

Tags: browser

My HP laptop loads internet browser by itself, then loads multiple pages and refreshes the page over and over. this laptop has been worked on by Geek Squad but they have not been able to fix it.  Even replaced hard drive and memory still not fixed. What ever browser is default loads by itself and loads multiple pages, if you go to a web site it will redirect back to home page. Please advise, am stuck and frustrated.Symptoms act like a virus but none detected and with a new hard drive how could it be.

Comment: If it's not a virus, my guess is the keyboard is faulty. Some of them have special keys including one to launch a browser. Please post a picture of your laptop keyboard.

Comment: Also, see if it happens in safe mode. See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7

Comment: When they replaced the HDD did they install the operating system again?

Answer (score 0):

Though this question leads quite naturally into many sub-questions and their answers, which vary depending on further details, the next steps can be advised as is.

First, don't panic. Of the possible causes of all your browsers opening on their own, going to the home page, and redirecting back to the home page, viruses are the least productive direction to devote energy at this stage. Not all possible causes are terminal for your computer, data, or wallet.

Second, you need to gather more data and share it with anyone who is helping you diagnose this problem. That  includes us here on Super User (in the form of searching for existing resources, applying them, then asking another, more pointed question, with details, when you are stuck).

Hardware problems such as a stuck keyboard key, cable problem, or failing keyboard are the most likely to have survived the work you've had done. If you don't still have any files or settings from your old hard drive it almost has to be hardware. Look into how to diagnose a failing keyboard and start there. Terms such as "reseat keyboard cable" will be valuable and "boot without keyboard enabled" are valuable. Try turning off the keyboard after booting up if the latter is not possible.

Viruses are still possible after installing a new hard drive depending upon the procedure Geek Squad used. Specifically, if you had the same personal files and settings when you got it back with the new hard drive they may have "imaged" the old one onto it. In that case a virus (or problematic setting) would have been transferred in the image. Even if they did not do a full image, viruses could be present in your personal files regardless of how they were transferred. Run scans with a trusted anti-virus or two.